# Returning a Gesture - Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trying to create a function that increments a value, then returns the longPress gesture. Receiving the following

> Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements
> in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Reason behind the function would be because I have three buttons that will increase on increments of one.

```
struct CustomFoodItemView: View {
    @State var foodName = ""
    @State var proteinAmount = 1
    @State var carbAmount = 1
    @State var fatAmount = 1
   
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State var isLongPressing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let releaseGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0) // << detects finger release
            .onEnded { _ in
                self.timer?.invalidate()
            }
        
        func longPressAction ( macroToIncrease: inout Int) -> some Gesture{
            let longPressGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2)
                .onEnded { _ in
                    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                        macroToIncrease += 1
                    })
                    
                }
            return longPressGesture
        }
        
        let proteinCombined = longPressAction(macroToIncrease: &proteinAmount).sequenced(before: releaseGesture)
        
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Food Name")
                TextField("", text: $foodName)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .border(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .frame(width:100, height:10)
            }
            HStack{
                Text(String(proteinAmount) + "g")
                    .frame(width:50, height:50)
                
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("SuccessButtonColor"))
                        .onTapGesture{
                            proteinAmount += 1
                        }
                        .gesture(proteinCombined)
                        
                       
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("SuccessButtonColor"))
                 
            }
              
            }
        }
        Spacer()
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
       
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing too much *controller* stuff in the view. A function is completely misplaced inside a view.

Comment: Always looking to improve, thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the multiple `let` variables, the view does not know what to display/ return. Put a `return` before the outer VStack to fix that.

Then remove some curly braces and fix your `longPressAction` function.
This should help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-use-gestures-in-swiftui.

Fixed code:

```
struct CustomFoodItemView: View {
    @State var foodName = ""
    @State var proteinAmount = 1
    @State var carbAmount = 1
    @State var fatAmount = 1
      
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State var isLongPressing = false
       
    var body: some View {
        let releaseGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0) // << detects finger release
            .onEnded { _ in
                self.timer?.invalidate()
            }
           
        let longPressGesture = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2)
            .onEnded { _ in
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    proteinAmount += 1
                })
            }
           
        let proteinCombined = longPressGesture.sequenced(before: releaseGesture)
           
        return VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Food Name")
                TextField("", text: $foodName)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .border(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 10)
            }
            HStack {
                Text(String(proteinAmount) + "g")
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                   
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("SuccessButtonColor"))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        proteinAmount += 1
                    }
                    .gesture(proteinCombined)
                   
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("SuccessButtonColor"))
            }
               
            Spacer()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```